# Solving $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{k}{k^4+k^2+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{k}{k^4+k^2+1}$$

Wolfram Alpha/Mathematica gives the precise answer in terms of a gamma function, but the numeric answer seems to be $\frac{1}{2}$. Is there any actual way to manipulate and telescope this sum somehow to arrive at that answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that $k^4+k^2+1 = (k^2+1)^2 - k^2 = (k^2+k+1)(k^2-k+1)$. Hence,
$$\dfrac{k}{k^4 + k^2 + 1} = \dfrac12\left(\dfrac1{k^2-k+1} - \dfrac1{k^2+k+1}\right) = \dfrac12 \left(\dfrac1{k(k-1)+1} - \dfrac1{(k+1)k+1}\right)$$
Now telescope to get the answer. Using the above, in general, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N} \dfrac{k}{k^4 + k^2 + 1} = \dfrac12 - \dfrac12\dfrac1{N^2+N+1}$$
Taking the limit as $N \to \infty$, we get $\dfrac12$.

Comment: Ah... got it! Only $\frac{1}{(k-1) k+1}$ is left after telescoping and the value at $x=0$ is 1 so that is how you get $\frac{1}{2}$!

Comment: @user2612743 Yes

Comment: Ramanujan you are alive?? :P

Comment: @Just_a_fool: No. But [Euler](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/38265/euler-is-alive) is. :-)